# Excel IF statement comparing cells

Tags: excel

I would like to seek a help regarding the if statement of excel,

I would like to compare a cell(example: if H2 = absent,no logs, R2 = 1)

I cannot formulate a formula for that statement.

Comment: What do you want in R2 if H2 does contain 'absent,no logs' ?

Answer (score 0):

Without **VBA** click on cell **R2** and enter:

```
=IF(H2="absent,no logs",1,"")
```

Comment: Thanks!

but there is no value in the R2 cell. did you know what is the problem?

Comment: There are **two** possible problems........first make sure the contents of **H2** matches the text EXACTLY with no extra spaces and no double-quotes............second make sure the calculation mode is set to **Automatic**